# How can I get 'minimum password age' of user in active directory using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, membership-provider

How can I get 'minimum password age' of user in active directory using asp.net?
Using directory services or `AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`

**For Example:**

```
from below line, I can get lastname of user. 
string lastName = objDirectoryEntry.Properties["sn"].Value;
```

Below is the list of user attributes.I could not find in my required attribute 'minimum password age'
http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

**Note:I am taking about using Asp.net**

**Edit Summary**-----------------------
I get following error when I try to change user password using directory service or 
`AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` (it is default membership provider)

*The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements*

User created and updated successfully(update field like firstname,lastname etc).I am using both directory services and AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to create and update
user,But problem is with when I try to change password

For example:
I created user with password anc1236! that created successfully
and now update password to xyyz4562@ and got error

below is the code that I am using to change password
`objMembershipUser.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword)`
I also try with using directory services directly and get same error

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking at the wrong objects.

> When working with user accounts in Active Directory, it is common to
>   need to refer to domain-wide account policies. For example, policies
>   such as the minimum and maximum password age and the minimum password
>   length, as well as lockout policy, are determined at the domain level
>   and apply to each user object in the domain. All of the values are
>   stored directly in the domain root object (not in RootDSE, but in the
>   object pointed to by the defaultNamingContext attribute in RootDSE) as
>   a set of attributes such as maxPwdAge, minPwdLength, and
>   lockoutThreshold. Additionally, the password complexity rules are
>   encoded in an enumerated value in the pwdProperties attribute. These
>   values tend to be quite static in most domains, so we would typically
>   want to read these values only once per program execution. To make the
>   policy values easy to consume, we show in Listing 10.7 a wrapper class
>   for the domain account policies that converts all of the values into
>   convenient .NET data types, such as TimeSpan. A special .NET
>   enumeration type for the types of the password policy is also
>   included. We won’t be able to include all of the class properties in
>   the book, as that would take too much space, but we will have the full
>   class available on the book’s web site. We will refer to this sample
>   in future discussions when demonstrating how to determine an account’s
>   lockout status and for finding accounts with expiring passwords. It is
>   also worthy to note that any LargeInteger values in these policy
>   attributes are stored as negative values. We chose to invert them back
>   to positive values because it is easier to think about them in this
>   way. Developers choosing to use these attributes should keep this in
>   mind, as it will throw off calculations later if not accounted for.

Look at [this](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Determining_Domain-Wide_Account_Policies) page for examples

Comment: Unfortunately, the link no longer works.